# Sharing Log4j2 jars within an EAR to prevent log stoppage

Tags: log4j, weblogic, war, log4j2, ear

Our application consists of one ear file, with 3 war files within the ear. I have come across situations where logging stops for one or more of the war. For example, after sometime, only one war is logging, or eventually all wars stop logging. When it stops logging, it is across all JVMs in a cluster. There are individual log files per jvm as configured by using ${sys:weblogic.NAME}.

The application contains a parent pom which currently has the log4j dependencies in it. Thus, all the wars and jars built from the application contain the log4j dependencies. My inclination from readings online is that all the wars should be sharing one set of log4j library - and not have their own.

Per https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/logsep.html
"...The logging classes will generally be placed in a location shared across all the components and the configuration needs to also be shareable..."

As suggested, I am trying to place the dependencies "in a location shared across all components". I've attempted to put them in the ear folder in WEB-INF/lib, APP-INF/lib, and /lib. However, it never logs. The *only* time i've gotten it to work was placing all the jars in the[ domain home]/lib directory. However, because we have several applications in the domain I do not want my requirements to impact other applications - so do not want it domain wide.

My questions are
1) Has anyone come across the same situation where logging just stops for individual wars?
2) Where do I need to place my log4j dependencies, so it can be shared by the components of only my application?

I've removed the dependency from the parent pom, and in the wars designate the scope as provided. I've put the dependency only in the ear pom.xml

Dependencies

```
<log4j2.version>2.6.2</log4j2.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>


<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>  
  <version>${log4j2.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>  
  <version>${log4j2.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>  
  <version>${log4j2.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<!-- slf4j bridge -->  
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>  
  <version>${log4j2.version}</version>  
</dependency>    
<!-- slf4j jcl -->  
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>  
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>  
  <version>1.7.7</version>  
</dependency>
```

In the pom.xml Plugin -> Configuration -> Modules

```
<!-- log4j 2 -->  
  <jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
  </jarModule>  
  <jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
  </jarModule>  
  <jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
  </jarModule>  

  <!-- slf4j bridge -->  
  <jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
  </jarModule>  

  <!-- slf4j jcl -->  
  <jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
  </jarModule>  


<jarModule>  
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>  
  <bundleDir>WEB-INF/lib</bundleDir>  
</jarModule>
```

In the weblogic.xml for all of my wars, I have

```
<wls:container-descriptor>  
  <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>  
  <wls:prefer-application-packages>  
  <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>  
  <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>  
  <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>  
  <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>  
  </wls:prefer-application-packages>  


  <wls:prefer-application-resources>  
  <wls:resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</wls:resource-name>  
  </wls:prefer-application-resources>  
</wls:container-descriptor>
```